# Getting additional fields with Identity 2.0 in Layout page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

I have an issue that I assumed would be a simple fix, but has turned into a big problem.

On my `_Layout.cshtml` page, I just want to display the current user's first and last name. This is stored in the `AspNetUsers` database table in the `Name` column. I currently have this on the layout page:

```
<h5>@Context.User.Identity.Name</h5>
```

This just displays the Username for that user, and `Name` is the only property available. Is there a way to overload the Identity to expose the user's full name?

This wouldn't be a big issue if it was only on one page, then I could just load that user data in the controller, but it needs to be shared across all pages in the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the information is stored as claims. Then you can access it via the claims identity like this:

```
@((ClaimsIdentity)Context.User.Identity).FindFirstValue("fullnameclaimname");
```

If the claim does not exist (check the `Claims` property of the `ClaimsIdentity`) you can add it when you authenticate the user in the `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` of the `ApplicationUser` class. In this method you generate the `ClaimsIdentity` from an `ApplicationUser`.